# How to perform page transition in DHTMLx Touch

Tags: javascript, mobile-application, dhtmlx

I'm using DHTMLx Touch to build a web app.

I'm stuck with the page transition.

I dont know how to perform page transition.

Can anyone pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use multiview, which allows to animate page changing. Check this sample in the framework package: /samples/technical/multiview/02_multiview_animations.html